# Ubuntu freezes again and again

Tags: ati, hp, radeon

I have purchased a new HP laptop with AMD processor and Radeon graphics (Processor - AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4 Graphic Card - Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS). I've decided to install Ubuntu on it.

After two days, the system freezes again and again and no response any more. Even <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does not work. I have to force shut down.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What model is your HP laptop, with what processor and graphics card? What is the output of `lspci -v`? (you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/608725/edit) this into your question)

Answer (score 0):

Gallium is the default and generic driver for this video card. I had a similar issue so I had to install the privative video driver (fglrx-updates) and it solved all.